# Unable to start Weechat with Whastapp script

Tags: python, whatsapp, manjaro, yowsup, weechat

I'm starting to learn Linux from scratch. I have some degree of knowledge and experience with Ubuntu, Kubuntu and now Manjaro.
In my Manjaro installation, I can't get Weechat to work with its Whatsapp script (and yowsup).
I apparently installed everything correctly, but Weechat still doesn't recognize the Whatsapp script.
Weechat quotes:

> python: stdout/stderr (?): Package python-yowsup (yowsup) must be installed to use whatsapp protocol.
> python: stdout/stderr (?): Get yowsup with your package manager, or at
> this URL: https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup
> python: stdout/stderr (?): Traceback (most recent call last):
> python: stdout/stderr (?):   File "/home/elnt/.local/share/weechat/python/autoload/whatsapp.py", line 395, in 
> python: stdout/stderr (?):     class Server(YowInterfaceLayer):
> python: stdout/stderr (?): NameError: name 'YowInterfaceLayer' is not defined
> =!= | python: unable to parse file "/home/elnt/.local/share/weechat/python/autoload/whatsapp.py"

While searching for files on disk named "python-yowsup" nothing is found, only "yowsup-cli" is found on /usr/bin and /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yowsup-3.3.0-py3.10.egg/EGG-INFO. So I tried duplicating the files found and renaming it to "yowsup" and another named "python-yowsup", but the Weechat issues persists.

My intentions here are not only using Whatsapp with Weechat, but learning along with the errors and mistakes I'm making, and building knowledge with all.

Thanks in advance!